Good practises for writing equation-heavy thesis in LaTeX
I'm starting to write my PhD thesis in LaTeX using the yathesis documentclass for french thesis.
I will write lots of equations, with many different symbols and I like the idea of referencing them with the glossaries package, for several reasons :

readers can refer to a list of symbols at the beginning of the document,
equations are written semantically in the source code, preventing many mistakes,
easy to make formatting changes for a particular symbol.

The problems are that : (i) I have many many symbols, (ii) some symbols take several form along the document, ex \varepsilon_{ij} or \varepsilon_{kl} represent the same variable, but with different summation indices.
Here are my questions :

[technical] What would be some good practices for easier writing these symbols and reference them efficiently ?
[advice] Should I include all these symbols in my table of symbols ? Obviously I would like \varepsilon_{ij} and \varepsilon_{kl} to both point to a single entry, but what about G^{elas}, G^{chem} and G^{grad} ? Do you think it would be of interest to have separate entries for each of them or just say that G is any kind of energy (Gibbs energy to be precise)?

I know about the \glsuseri{...} command, but I will have a hard time remembering all the combinaisons for 1 symbol, and it would take away from the clarity of the equations in the source code.

not directly related to your question but G^{grad} would be wrong, don't use math italic for words it is designed to make adjacent letters look like a product of 1-letter variables, use G^{\mathrm{Grad}}  etc

I use my own package, semantex, specifically to keep the notation semantic, as per your second reason. But that package is doubtlessly not for everyone.

Thank you for the package suggestion, indeed it looks very interesting!
